# Zeppelin Air wireless connection through Netgear router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

My laptop cannot connect to a Zeppelin Air (B&W). How can I get it working?

Comment: before someone can give you a decent advice you should supply them with decent information. what OS are you using, what have you tried, are you getting any errors? I don't even know what a zeppelin air is, maybe a link would clear that, especially if there is a generic solution to your seemingly specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues that could be giving you a problem.

Have you connected your Zeppelin Air to the same network as your laptop? Is a wired connection, or is it connected wirelessly?

From what I can tell, the wireless setup is fairly complex. Have you read the [manual](http://www.bowers-wilkins.co.uk/Downloads/Product/Manual/ENG_FP30570_Zeppelin-Air_manual.pdf)?

If it is a wired connection, you can use this [quick set up](http://www.bowers-wilkins.co.uk/Downloads/Product/Support/ZeppelinAir/Zeppelin-Air-QSG-Wired-SetUp.pdf) guide.

It is hard to provide specific help without a specific description of exactly what is wrong.